# How to copy json file into postgres sql

Tags: psql

database=# create table insights(

database(# end_year varchar,

database(# intensity int,

database(# sector varchar,

database(# topic varchar,

database(# insight varchar,

database(# url varchar,

database(# region varchar,

database(# start_year varchar,

database(# impact varchar,

database(# added varchar,

database(# published varchar,

database(# country varchar,

database(# relevance int,

database(# pestle varchar,

database(# source varchar,

database(# title varchar,

database(# likelihood int);

when i tried to copy json file insert into this table its getting error can any one solve?

database=# \COPY insights FROM 'C:/Users/arsha/Downloads/jsondata.json';

ERROR:  missing data for column "intensity"

CONTEXT:  COPY insights, line 1: " ["

some of the json i used to copy are below

```
 {
            "end_year": "",
            "intensity": 6,
            "sector": "Energy",
            "topic": "gas",
            "insight": "Annual Energy Outlook",
            "url": "http://www.eia.gov/outlooks/aeo/pdf/0383(2017).pdf",
            "region": "Northern America",
            "start_year": "",
            "impact": "",
            "added": "January, 20 2017 03:51:25",
            "published": "January, 09 2017 00:00:00",
            "country": "United States of America",
            "relevance": 2,
            "pestle": "Industries",
            "source": "EIA",
            "title": "U.S. natural gas consumption is expected to increase during much of the projection period.",
            "likelihood": 3
        },
        {
            "end_year": "",
            "intensity": 6,
            "sector": "Energy",
            "topic": "oil",
            "insight": "Annual Energy Outlook",
            "url": "http://www.eia.gov/outlooks/aeo/pdf/0383(2017).pdf",
            "region": "Northern America",
            "start_year": "",
            "impact": "",
            "added": "January, 20 2017 03:51:24",
            "published": "January, 09 2017 00:00:00",
            "country": "United States of America",
            "relevance": 2,
            "pestle": "Industries",
            "source": "EIA",
            "title": "Reference case U.S. crude oil production is projected to recover from recent declines.",
            "likelihood": 3
        },
```

```
 {
            "end_year": "",
            "intensity": 6,
            "sector": "Energy",
            "topic": "gas",
            "insight": "Annual Energy Outlook",
            "url": "http://www.eia.gov/outlooks/aeo/pdf/0383(2017).pdf",
            "region": "Northern America",
            "start_year": "",
            "impact": "",
            "added": "January, 20 2017 03:51:25",
            "published": "January, 09 2017 00:00:00",
            "country": "United States of America",
            "relevance": 2,
            "pestle": "Industries",
            "source": "EIA",
            "title": "U.S. natural gas consumption is expected to increase during much of the projection period.",
            "likelihood": 3
        },
        {
            "end_year": "",
            "intensity": 6,
            "sector": "Energy",
            "topic": "oil",
            "insight": "Annual Energy Outlook",
            "url": "http://www.eia.gov/outlooks/aeo/pdf/0383(2017).pdf",
            "region": "Northern America",
            "start_year": "",
            "impact": "",
            "added": "January, 20 2017 03:51:24",
            "published": "January, 09 2017 00:00:00",
            "country": "United States of America",
            "relevance": 2,
            "pestle": "Industries",
            "source": "EIA",
            "title": "Reference case U.S. crude oil production is projected to recover from recent declines.",
            "likelihood": 3
        },
```

i want to insert the json inside the file into table without entering each manually.

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)   (quote: [Introduce the problem before you post any code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=Introduce%20the%20problem%20before%20you%20post%20any%20code) )

Answer (score -1):

The error you're encountering is due to the fact that PostgreSQL's `COPY` command doesn't support JSON format directly. However, there are a few ways to work around this.

One way is to use a tool like `jq` to convert the JSON file into a CSV file, which PostgreSQL can import using the `COPY` command. Here's an example of how you might do this:

```
jq -r '.[] | [.end_year,.intensity,.sector,.topic,.insight,.url,.region,.start_year,.impact,.added,.published,.country,.relevance,.pestle,.source,.title,.likelihood] | @csv' jsondata.json > jsondata.csv
```

Then you can import the CSV file into your PostgreSQL table:

```
COPY insights FROM '/path/to/jsondata.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV);
```

**Another way** is to use a PostgreSQL function to import the JSON file. Here's an example of how you might do this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION import_json_file(filename text)
RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
   line text;
BEGIN
   FOR line IN (SELECT * FROM read_file(filename))
   LOOP
       INSERT INTO insights
       SELECT * FROM json_populate_record(NULL::insights, line);
   END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This function reads the file line by line and inserts each line into the `insights` table. The `json_populate_record` function is used to convert the JSON text into a record that matches the structure of the table.

OBS: you need to have the read_file function available in your PostgreSQL database. This function is provided by the file_fdw extension, which you can install using the following command:

```
CREATE EXTENSION file_fdw;
```

After creating the `import_json_file` function, you can call it like this:

```
SELECT import_json_file('C:/Users/arsha/Downloads/jsondata.json');
```

Comment: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: "intensity"
CONTEXT:  COPY insights, line 1, column instensity: "intensity"

Comment: The error you're encountering is because PostgreSQL is trying to insert the word "intensity" into the "intensity" column, which is expected to contain integer values. It seems that your JSON file might not be formatted correctly for direct insertion into the table.

To resolve this issue, you can use the json_populate_record function to insert JSON data into your PostgreSQL table, but this is another problem entirely